# Laravel function requests

Tags: laravel

I am a `laravel` beginner and wondering if there are pros and cons of using the name of the controller and assigning it to a variable in a function? The original code is:

```
public function postLogin()
{
        $email = Request::input('txt_email');
        $pword = Request::input('txt_pword');
}
```

And if you include the controller name in the function:

```
public function postLogin(ControllerName $request)
{
        $email = $request->input('txt_email');
        $pword = $request->input('txt_pword');
}
```

Is there a difference between this two? What would be the best to use? Thank you.

Comment: They both are do the same thing, first one is using Facade and second one using dependency injection. In Laravel 5 second one is encouraged to use.

Comment: Thank you Mr. NULL. How did you know that the second one is encouraged? Is it written in the docs? Thank you again!

Comment: @FewFlyBy I'm not sure if it's explicitly written in the docs, but if you look at the majority of examples in the **> 5.0** docs you will see they tend to use dependency injection over Facades.

Comment: Yeah it's not explicitly written in the does, but in L4 to L5 transition they  follow the "depend on abstractions, not concretions" rule. I know it isn't explain anything, but that's the concept. Its a vast thing, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whats-new-in-laravel-5--cms-21842 I think from here you will have some idea.

Comment: My opinion: The main benefit of using dependency injection is i know which object i am injecting and do a lot of other preprocessing on that. but in facade you won't have that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: Facade vs DI (when to use)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193532/laravel-4-facade-vs-di-when-to-use)